# How to execute a post request from another application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a microservice with an endpoint of 
`http://www.example.com/create` which makes a post request. In this request, I make use of `ResponseEntity` class i.e.

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
   //do some other stuff i.e. validation
   someService.createUser(user);
   URI location = ...;
   return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

Now I want to call the post request `/create` from another application i.e. whilst accessing `http://www.example-2.com/signup` call `/create` to create user entity.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ModelAndView createUser(@Valid UserForm form) {
   //How do I make `/create` post request to post 
   //the `form` entity 
   return new ModelAndView("some view");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spring [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/). Here is [tutorial example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) on how to use it. You can just create a singleton bean of RestTemplate and autowire in the controller class and use it to make the rest call.

```
String response = restTemplate.postForObject("https://your-domain/create",user, String.class)
```